# Logging into a deceased relative's Facebook account

Tags: facebook, account-management

How can I gain access to a Facebook account of a deceased family member?

Is there a procedure or appropriate channels we must go through via Facebook in order to gain access to the account of a dead family member?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Facebook will not allow anybody to access a deceased user's account.

> Please note, to protect the privacy of our members, we cannot provide anyone with login information for accounts.

You can submit requests for deceased family members' accounts through Facebook's help center:

- [Deceased users - special requests](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=memorialize_special_requests) allows for family members to make special requests for how a deceased person's account should be handled.
- [Report a deceased person's profile](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=deceased) allows for users to request that a deceased member's account be memorialized. Memorialization entails:

  > When a user passes away, we memorialize their account to protect their privacy. Memorializing an account sets the account privacy so that only confirmed friends can see the profile (timeline) or locate it in search. Friends and family can leave posts in remembrance. Memorializing an account also prevents anyone from logging into the account.

If the deceased user is involved with an ongoing investigation, law enforcement can contact Facebook to [request additional information](https://www.facebook.com/safety/groups/law/) relevant to the investigation. Most information requires a court order.